# How can I set rtc time in kernel space?

Tags: time, linux-kernel, kernel

I try set RTC from kernel space. But `rtc_set_time()` is blocking and does not return. `"111"` printed, and `"222"` not printed.

How can I set RTC time in Linux (2.6.32) kernel space?

```c
struct device *dev = NULL;
struct rtc_device *rtc_dev = NULL;
struct rtc_time rtc_tm;

/* set rtc_tm */
/* ... */

dev = bus_find_device_by_name(&platform_bus_type, NULL, "at91_rtt.0");
if (!dev) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "%s: NOT FIND DEVICE\n", __FUNCTION__);
    return -1;
}

rtc_dev = to_rtc_device(dev);

printk(KERN_INFO "%s: 111\n", __FUNCTION__);
ret = rtc_set_time(rtc_dev, &rtc_tm);
printk(KERN_INFO "%s: 222\n", __FUNCTION__);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[rtc_set_ntp_time()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/rtc/systohc.c#L23) in systohc.c file does similar. It calls [rtc_class_open()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/rtc/interface.c#L592) to get `rtc_dev` which calls `try_module_get()` to make sure that module hasn't been removed.

Not sure if `try_module_get()` solves the problem, but it's certainly a good thing to do.

Comment: Thanks for your hint.

Comment: `rtc_dev = rtc_class_open(CONFIG_RTC_HCTOSYS_DEVICE);`

Comment: Glad it helped :)